# Push Notification error using .NET to connect APNS

Tags: c#, ios, .net, push-notification

I am using .NET to connect and send push notification. Intermittently following error happens while connecting to APNS during  sending push notifications. It does not happen on Windows 2008 server but Windows 2012 server sometimes gives error:

```
Error=System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified data could not be decrypted
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckThrow(Boolean authSuccessCheck, Boolean shutdownCheck)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.get_SecureStream()
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.IO.Stream.<>c.<BeginEndWriteAsync>b__53_0(Stream stream, ReadWriteParameters args, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrim[TInstance,TArgs](TInstance thisRef, TArgs args, Func`5 beginMethod, Func`3 endMethod)
   at System.IO.Stream.BeginEndWriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Stream.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.IO.Stream.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
```

Answer (score 0):

TLS issue. Post your code for better responses.